How to theoretically derive phased spectra in NMR?
I came across the following question in my NMR course for chemists:

Assuming    that    magnetization along     the     y-axis  gives   rise    to  an  absorption  mode
lineshape,  draw    sketches    of  the spectra which   arise   from    the following   operators:
$I_{1y}$ ; $I_{2x}$ ; $2I_{1y}I_{2z}$ ; $2I_{1z}I_{2x}$
Describe   each    spectrum    in  words.

This is the solution I was provided with:

My questions: Why are the signals split? Why are there two offsets? How can I derive the line shape?
I understand how the shape of the signal - absorption or dispersion - is influenced by the phase of the magnetisation vector. I read the chapter 8.4 about signal phases in the textbook “NMR spectroscopy” by Günther. However, I am still quite unsure how to approach this question, so I would appreciate any explanation or advice. References of any kind are welcomed. As mentioned, I mostly use Günthers and Keelers textbooks for learning.
